# A simple picture for work fluctuation relations?

Tags: thermodynamics, stochastic-processes, fluctuation-dissipation

One possible formulation of the second law of thermodynamics is that the work extracted during the change of a thermodynamic system between two thermodynamic states is at most equal to the free energy difference between those two states.

One possible derivation of this empirical result from statistical mechanics is the derivation of Jarzinski relation in the canonical ensemble. Also, the Jarzinski relation was also derived in a stochastic setting by Crooks. For the sake of further simplifying the statement of the Jarzinski relation, I consider a Brownian particle fluctuating within a double-well potential in one dimension, i.e subject a Langevin equation on the real axis with known potential and noise.

What I can say for this system is that the particle will be undergoing transitions between the two wells with a rate that is exponential in the barrier height of those two wells. Also, the equilibrium distribution of the particle will be a bi-modal having a peak at each potential minimum, and the height of each peak is given by the barrier height.

Now which additional useful information does the Jarzinsky relation tell me about this simple system ?